# Firebird connection in C#

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

i have problem with connection..

I can connect without problems to my database, when this database is downloaded on my computer:

```
viewdataConnection.ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:F:\\machine.FDB;DataSource=localhost;Charset=NONE;"
```

everything is working fine.

But problems starts when i try to connect to this base in lan network:

```
viewdataConnection.ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=10.48.14.51:d:\\backup\\machine.fdb; DataSource=:d:\\backup\\machine.fdb;Charset=NONE;";
```

and this don't work also:

```
viewdataConnection.ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=10.48.14.51:d:\\backup\\maszyna.fdb; DataSource=:10.48.14.51:d:\\backup\\maszyna.fdb;Charset=NONE;";
```

then i get error about invalid token "second" in my sql query, but this query works when database is on localhost.. so probably there's mistake in my connectionstring..

Why?

Comment: I don't understand. You tell us 'problems with base on lan network' but the paths you give in the example refers to a local path. They shoulf be something like '\\server\share\database.fdb'

Comment: Sorry for not clear explanation, check my edit - i want to connect to database located on 10.48.14.51 in my network..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your datasource part should be datasource=10.48.14.51 without any extra path.
The database part should be your network path to the database like "database=\server\path\database.fdb"

Putting all together I will try in this way:

```
viewdataConnection.ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;" + 
"Database=\\server\share\database.fdb;DataSource=10.48.14.51;Charset=NONE;";
```

of course you need to change \server\share\database.fdb with your exact network path.

Comment: This is good, but... server runs on old version of firebird without function that i use :)