# Connect to Firebird on Mono

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, firebird

Im trying to connect to a Firebird server using Mono on Mac but it is throwing an exception that I have no idea whats is happening.

I installed the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient

and here is the code I am using:

```
var connectionString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();

connectionString.DataSource = "xxxx";
connectionString.UserID = "xxxxx";
connectionString.Password = "xxxxxx";
connectionString.Database = "/xxxxx.gdb";
connectionString.Charset = "NONE";

FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(connectionString.ToString());

try
{
    connection.Open();

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

And the exception:

```
String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s

  at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes (System.String s) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs:1083 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.GdsConnection.UserIdentificationData () [0x00141] in <1c49352b896a4a9dba73865ddab7b59e>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.GdsConnection.Identify (System.String database) [0x00044] in <1c49352b896a4a9dba73865ddab7b59e>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateManagedDatabase (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionString options) [0x00042] in <1c49352b896a4a9dba73865ddab7b59e>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateDatabase (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionString options) [0x00010] in <1c49352b896a4a9dba73865ddab7b59e>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect () [0x0001e] in <1c49352b896a4a9dba73865ddab7b59e>:0 
  at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open () [0x000b7] in <1c49352b896a4a9dba73865ddab7b59e>:0
```

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: There is still an error in the connection string definition. As there are only x for us to see it is hard to guess. Compare your strings to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9631097/3090544

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/src/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/Client/Managed/GdsConnection.cs#L285 one of the few things that could cause this would be `Dns.GetHostName()` to return null. Unless you are using a much older version.

Comment: I tested the same code lines on windows and it worked.

Comment: I replaced the the dns with the ip address but the error is still there

Comment: I got the latest master code from github to debug BUT It worked =)